# Why do Chinese universities hold many more patents than other universities?

Tags: united-states, patents, china

On the list of [top 250 largest patent holders worldwide](https://www.ificlaims.com/rankings-global-assets-2021.htm) (2021), I see that Chinese universities hold many more patents than other universities, even normalizing by population size or student population size. Why? I am especially interested in the difference between China and the USA.

Universities ranked by number of active patent families* from the link above:

| Rank | Name | # active patent families | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Chinese Academy of Sciences CAS | 78,415 | China |
| 16 | Tsinghua University | 31,368 | China |
| 34 | Zhejiang University ZJU | 21,805 | China |
| 76 | Zhejiang University of Technology ZJUT | 11,053 | China |
| 109 | Dalian University of Technology | 7,932 | China |
| 112 | National Research Council of Science and Technology | 7,803 | South Korea |
| 119 | Nanjing University of Aeronautics and Astronautics | 7,373 | China |
| 124 | China University of Mining and Technology CUMT | 7,014 | China |
| 151 | University of California | 5,603 | USA |
| 157 | Centre National de la Recherche Scientifique CNRS | 5,370 | France |
| 218 | Capital Medical University | 3,739 | China |

---

*An active patent family [is](https://www.ificlaims.com/rankings-help.htm):

> a collection of global patent filings related to a single invention. For example, if a company invents a new technology and files related patent applications in 10 countries, that represents one patent family. Further we only count patent families that are active – which contain at least one current, granted patent. This is a patent that can be enforced and that has not expired.

Comment: How did you select the universities in your table?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I tried to extract all universities from the top 250. I may have missed a few ones.

Comment: I am confused by your response. There are not 250 universities in that table, nor are they all from China, suggesting it isn't a list of the highest-ranking Chinese universities.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I tried to extract all universities from the [list of the top 250 largest patent holders worldwide](https://www.ificlaims.com/rankings-global-assets-2021.htm). (Most of the 250 largest patent holders are companies.)

Comment: If you count public not-exactly-university research institutions as CNRS (#157) for the list, arguably the Fraunhofer Gesellschaft (#163) should also be included. Also on the list are #239 Zhejiang University of Science and Technology ZUST and #241 Zhejiang Ocean University ZJOU.

Comment: I don't have a source for this as it's from personal knowledge, but may Chinese institutes require people to apply for patents or to have published papers, so you tend to get a lot of people doing things that are simply small incremental changes on existing papers or patents. They're basically paper\patent farms because of this.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt that approach to gathering your data could also lead to a TON of problems, if China has few but large patent-filing universites and the US has a lot of smaller actively patenting universities. By selecting only the 10 largest unis (by patents) such a centralization skews the data massively

Comment: @Hobbamok agreed. Answers are welcome to contradict claims present in the question.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yeah, but I'm just speculating and still too much in holiday mode for the serious research an answer would require, sry

Answer (score 22):

I suspect there are two main reasons.

1. There are substantial subsidies for patent applications in China
2. Chinese patents are generally of lower quality; thus it takes less work to file them, and there is a lower bar on what to patent.

##### Patent Subsidies

It costs a lot of money to file a patent application in the US. Meanwhile, in China, [currently](http://english.www.gov.cn/statecouncil/ministries/202201/27/content_WS61f29de1c6d09c94e48a4616.html), there are monetary subsidies from various levels of government for filing patents.

[Lei and colleagues](https://funginstitute.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/patent_subsidy_Zhen.pdf) wrote about this issue in 2013:

> Other observers, however, believe that the patent
> boom is largely due to various patent subsidy policies implemented by local governments to meet and/or exceed the patenting targets specified by the government.³

They go on to note:

> it’s likely that the increase in the number of applications is due to
> patentees broke up their patents to get more applications (and thus more subsidies).

##### Patent Quality

The other issue is patent quality. In my personal experience with university patent offices in the US, the professionals that work there are very interested in if your invention is of significant enough quality and commercial value before filing for a patent--after all, it costs a lot of money.

Because of the subsidies, universities in China may be less interested in patent quality. The bar is lower, allowing more patent applications.

[Hefa and Zhenxing wrote about this in 2014](https://www.law.berkeley.edu/files/Song_Hefa_IPSC_paper_2014.pdf) :

> Based on the analysis above, it is discovered that of all the four aspects of patent quality, China falls behind in quality for invention, document quality, and quality for commercialization... The lagging behind quality for commercialization shows the reality that Chinese patents are less commercially valuable. The average royalty and license fee is
> significantly lower compared with developed countries.

In conclusion, there are subsidies from the Chinese government that incentivize more patent applications. Further, the quality of the resulting patents is lower.

[The Chinese government seems to agree](http://english.www.gov.cn/statecouncil/ministries/202201/27/content_WS61f29de1c6d09c94e48a4616.html):

> China plans to stop all patent subsidies by 2025 to help shift its intellectual property (IP) focus from quantity to quality.

Comment: Please consider an additional possible reason. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegations_of_intellectual_property_theft_by_China

Comment: @BillOnne I'm a bit confused by your comment. Are you suggesting Chinese universities are filing patents on stolen US intellectual property?

Comment: @Ian not sure about stolen, but they do patent translated documents and publish translated papers, and some people fluent in Mandarin have suggested that many of those are on the level of Google Translate quality (personal communication). But the key here is still, of course, perverse incentives - subsidies are given away without real supervision, because targets have to be met.

Comment: @Ian if you get money for every patent filed and google translate + not-yet-patented US ideas (maybe because of the higher bars there) are public, why not grab the free money

Comment: In the US, many patents owned by private companies are based on research conducted at public universities. If this happens to a lesser degree in China, that could have an impact as well.

Comment: @Ian Yes, this definitely happens. I know a professor with a US patent that was stolen/re-patented in China. (I'm fuzzy on the exact details and whether or not backdating was involved)

Answer (score 4):

My two cents:

- It is part of their performance metric.  In other words, having patents count toward their promotion or continuation of their employment.
- Many academics own side businesses; there is a huge incentive to do so given their low salary.  Hence, many seek to commercialize their research outputs.

Comment: Aren't these two points  true in the USA as well?

Comment: No idea.  I'm not familiar with the system in the USA.  I am aware that universities such as MIT like patents because its a huge source of income for the uni, but probably not others.

Comment: Being a Chinese, I know these two points are true. No idea if they are the main reasons that Chinese universities hold many more patents than other universities.

Comment: I have no idea as well, but I somehow believe that there is a "patent" race in China, and the biggest opponent is US

Comment: The secondary answer was sort of disproven by the other answer, Chinese university patents generate far less royalty on average, which is what we would see if financial exploitation of the patents were a priority.